# How do I use a dropdown box as a column header filter in ng-grid / ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, filter, header, ng-grid

I am using ui-grid (angular's fast grid system).
If I set 'enableFiltering: true', I get an text box under each column header that I can use to filter the grid, awesome.
Now I need some or even all of these to be dropdown boxes instead of text boxes, how would I achieve this?

e.g. The one column can only have the values 'OK', 'NOK' and 'ABB.'. So I would like to allow the user to filter that column based on only those 3 options.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should write custom [`headerCellTemplate`](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#headerCellFilter) in `columnDefs`.