# Dropdown menu in angular ui-grid column not dropping down

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to insert a dropdown menu into a column in ui-grid. Each menu item will have an ng-click attached.

I am using ui-grid-unstable.min.js because pagination doesn't seem to work in ui-grid-stable.min.js

The button appears in the grid and registers that it has been clicked on (the open class is added to it) but it doesn't dropdown.

My ui-grid columndef look like this:

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
{ field: 'Foo', displayName: 'Actions', cellTemplate: '/app/quiz/action.html', sortable: false }
];
```

The cellTemplate code comes from the "Dropdown on Body" button example https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
It looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
    Dropdown on Body <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ui.bootstrap is included in my app module and the .css and .js files are included in my index.html

I looked at this: [Angular UI Grid: How to create a pre-populated dropdown menu for column filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097758/angular-ui-grid-how-to-create-a-pre-populated-dropdown-menu-for-column-filterin) and some others but they seem to deal with creating bound selects (not a drop-down menu) and searched other similar items on stack overflow but I cannot find one that solves my problem of the button menu not even dropping down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further research shows it was because the class on the ui-grid cell is overflow hidden. By adding a class with overflow:visible the columnDef for the cell I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Interesting. I was just trying this out and was able to get it working without the overflow css: http://plnkr.co/edit/baiBVqc8DiWG17kztkt5?p=preview

Comment: That is odd. I notice my script include list is different than yours - it's `code`<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-grid-unstable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>`code`;

Answer (score 2):

Adding `dropdown-append-to-body` near the `uib-dropdown` or `dropdown` directive helps with `overflow:hidden` problem. Also inside the ui-grid cell.

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
...
</div>
```